# Do Not Track feature of IE10

Tags: php

One of our clients is getting a bit worried about the new "Do Not Track" feature of Internet Explorer 10. Her site is heavily dependent on php sessions (as I imagine many other sites are). This was what she was reading:

http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-18288710

I need some clarification, will this affect how sessions (or cookies) work on normal web sites that use the PHP $_SESSION array? Or is it regarding only how advertising works (engadget's article seems to insinuate this)?

Can anyone provide a more technical overview (and the ramifications) of PHP-powered websites?

Comment: IE changes things all the time. This may change before actually release of the software.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The article is misleading. Do Not Track is simply a header that is sent in requests *asking* not to track the user. This is mainly targeted at advertisers. Your own PHP sessions will not be affected in any way.

Comment: Awesome thank you, I can tell her there's no need to worry :)

Answer (score 2):

Do Not Track as implemented in most browsers is simply an additional HTTP header. It does not actually block any cookies.

It is up to the website operator to honor the HTTP header's value. A session cookie isn't tracking, so creating the cookie shouldn't be a problem, nor would it violate the spirit of Do Not Track.